# How do I get a list of distinct rows from the result of multiple joins in Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have performed a few joins which have produced multiple columns with the same CustomerId. I would like to filter the result to only display rows with distinct customer. It does not matter which duplicate rows are removed. Tried using group by but couldn't get it to work. After this is filtered I would like to do a select to create new CustomerDTO. This is my code, any assistance is appreciated.

```
var query = (from customer in db.Customers
                                     join person in db.People
                                     on customer.PersonId equals person.BusinessEntityId
                                     join phone in db.PeoplePhones
                                     on person.BusinessEntityId equals phone.BusinessEntityId into phoneNumbers
                                     from phone1 in phoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                     join email in db.EmailAddresses
                                     on person.BusinessEntityId equals email.BusinessEntityId into emailAddresses
                                     from email1 in phoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 
                                     select  new CustomerDTO
                                     {
                                         Id = customer.CustomerId,
                                         Title = person.Title,
                                         FirstName = person.FirstName,
                                         LastName = person.LastName,
                                         PhoneNumber = phoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber,
                                         EmailAddress = emailAddresses.FirstOrDefault().Email,
                                         Branch = customer.Branch.Name

                                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: What's this point of doing `from phone1 in phoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()` and `from email1 in phoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()`. If there are more than one of either you're just creating duplicate objects for no reason.

Comment: That's a good question. I was not sure about that, I saw this in an example somewhere when trying I was trying to do a left join using linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track using a group by. Does something like this do what you need to?

```
var query = (from customer in db.Customers
         join person in db.People on customer.PersonId equals person.BusinessEntityId
         join phone in db.PeoplePhones on person.BusinessEntityId equals phone.BusinessEntityId into phoneNumbers
         from phone1 in phoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty() join email in db.EmailAddresses on person.BusinessEntityId equals email.BusinessEntityId into emailAddresses
         from email1 in phoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()
         
         group new {customer, person, phoneNumbers, emailAddresses} by customer.CustomerId into g
         
         select new CustomerDTO
         {
             Id = g.FirstOrDefault().customer.CustomerId,
             Title = g.FirstOrDefault().person.Title,
             FirstName = g.FirstOrDefault().person.FirstName,
             LastName = g.FirstOrDefault().person.LastName,
             PhoneNumber = g.FirstOrDefault().phoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber,
             EmailAddress = g.FirstOrDefault().emailAddresses.FirstOrDefault().Email,
             Branch = g.FirstOrDefault().customer.Branch.Name
         }).ToList();
```

Since it looks like you're using linq-to-sql or EntityFramework, This should be a good solution to do the grouping on the SQL server side. Otherwise it's totally possible to do the grouping in memory after executing the `.ToList()`

Comment: Thank you @Joe_DM. Was not sure how to access to the objects through the group, this is a exactly what I was looking for . Much appreciated.

Comment: glad it works. If you're looking for a cleaner way to do a left join, you can try something like this using phone as example:
`from phoneNumbers in db.PeoplePhones.Where(x => person.BusinessEntityId == x.BusinessEntityId).DefaultIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

Can you give this a go and let me know if it works?

```
var query =
(
    from customer in db.Customers
    join person in db.People on customer.PersonId equals person.BusinessEntityId
    join phone in db.PeoplePhones on person.BusinessEntityId equals phone.BusinessEntityId into phoneNumbers
    join email in db.EmailAddresses on person.BusinessEntityId equals email.BusinessEntityId into emailAddresses
    group new { customer, person, phoneNumbers, emailAddresses } by customer.CustomerId into gs
    from g in gs.Take(1)
    from pn in g.phoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1)
    from e in g.emailAddresses.DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1)
    select new CustomerDTO
    {
        Id = g.customer.CustomerId,
        Title = g.person.Title,
        FirstName = g.person.FirstName,
        LastName = g.person.LastName,
        PhoneNumber = pn.PhoneNumber,
        EmailAddress = e.Email,
        Branch = g.customer.Branch.Name
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this and it works. This solution looks really clean. Does the g.phoneNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty().Take(1) mean that the join done earlier into phoneNumbers is left join?

Comment: I'm a tad confused how this becomes a left join, it looks like a right join to me unless the `DefaultIfEmpty` after the group by retrospectively turns it into a left join?

Comment: @Joe_DM - I don't know my left from my right, but it's the same as the original query.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree that it's the same from a pure c# perspective. As for a sql translation I'm not sure if it's smart enough to work that out. e.g. if the join on phone is null then person may be null before it gets to the default if empty part. I'm not sure either so without looking at the SQL generated it's just interesting to think about.